# Changing random variable in uniform distribution

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, means, change-of-variable

Let $X\sim U([1,2])$ and $Y=\frac{1}{X}$

How do I calculate the mean of Y?

I know that

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1
 & \text{ if } 1\leq x\leq 2 \\ 
 0& \text{ otherwise } 
\end{cases}$$

Does that mean that

$$f(y)=\begin{cases}1
 & \text{ if } 1\leq \frac{1}{y}\leq 2  \Leftrightarrow  \frac{1}{2}\leq y\leq 1\\
 0& \text{ otherwise } 
\end{cases}$$

if so then the mean value should be:

$$\int_{1/2}^{1}y=\int_{1/2}^{1}\frac{1}{x} dx$$

Is this correct?

Comment: You should be integrating $1/x$ but it should be from $1$ to $2$, not from $1/2$ to $1$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Could you explain why is that? I mean since we change the variable doesn't that mean that our new variable is in a new interval?

Comment: Defining $f$ is such a manner for $y$ does not satisfy the basic principle requiring the PDF to having the area bound between the curve and the x-axis equal 1.

Comment: @VakiPitsi  $\int_{1/2}^1 y\, f_Y(y)\,\mathrm d y = \int_{1}^2 x^{-1}\, f_X(x)\,\mathrm d x$

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

By the [Law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician),

$$
\mathbb{E}[Y] = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{X}\right] = \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{x} f_X(x)dx
= \int_1^2 \frac{1}{x} dx = \ln 2
$$
since $f_X(x) = \begin{cases}1 &\text{ if } 1\leq x\leq 2\\0& \text {otherwise.}\end{cases}$

Answer (score 0):

Use the transformation formula

$$p(Y)=p(X)\left|\frac{dX}{dY}\right|=\frac{1}{Y^2}$$
where $Y \in [\frac{1}{2},1]$

So
$$E[Y]=\int_{1/2}^1 Y\frac{1}{Y^2}dY=\int_{1/2}^1\frac{1}{Y}dY=\ln1-\ln\frac{1}{2}=\ln 2$$

Comment: Computing the PDF of Y is **not** necessary. Since the OP seems to believe it is, to confirm their misconception is not the most useful thing to do here.